# How long are you able to pause a firebase StorageUploadTask for?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload videos to firebase and depending on video length it could take up to 10 mins or longer. Chances are the user will terminate the app while the video is being uploaded, so I want to use a `BGProcessingTask` to resume uploading the firebase `StorageUploadTask` at a later time.

**Question:**

`BGProcessingTask` will only run when the users device is being charged and the device has a good connection. I am wondering how long am I able to pause a firebase `StorageUploadTask` for? What if the user doesn't charge their phone for a few days? Will the task eventually terminate itself and never upload to firebase? Or will it stay paused until it gets resumed?